# Flickering in JFrame

Tags: java, image-loading, jcanvas

Im working on a small game that will be for the enjoyment of my freinds and if come into an error. The Screen will flicker the images. I know this is from the canvas rendering the image every single frame. But I dont know how to stop it from rendering every frame. I was looking for help. This is a bit of code in my main, JFrameBuilder, and JCanvas class to show what im doing.

https://pastebin.com/renyzgXx

```
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import entity.Dragon;
import imageBuilders.Image;


public class Main {

public static JFrameBuilder jf ;

public static void main(String[] args){

    jf = new JFrameBuilder("Tutorial");


    try {
        JCanvas.addImage(new Image(ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Eddie/Desktop/testprog2/Tutorial game/src/imgs/Dragon.png")), null,100,100));
        JCanvas.addImage(new Image(ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Eddie/Desktop/testprog2/Tutorial game/src/imgs/rocket.png")), null,100,100));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int x = 0;

    Dragon d = new Dragon(jf,x);
    while(jf.isActive()){
    jf.update(jf.getGraphics());

    JCanvas.changeImageXandY(d.calculateX(), d.calculateY(), 0);
    System.out.println(d.calculateX());
    delay(16);
    }
}


public static void delay(long ms){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(ms);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

https://pastebin.com/ERisWs6V

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JFrameBuilder extends JFrame{
/**
 * Author: Kingmo100
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8535971463237805125L;
private static final int WIDTH = 1000;
private static final int HEIGHT = 500;
private static JCanvas jp;
public JFrameBuilder(String title){
    super(title);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    jp = new JCanvas();
    jp.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    jp.setLocation(10, HEIGHT + 10);
    jp.setAlignmentX(10);
    jp.setAlignmentY(10);
    jp.paintComponents(this.getGraphics());
    jp.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println(jp);
    this.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.getContentPane();

}

public static JCanvas getJCanvas(){
    return jp;
}

public JFrame getFrame(){
    return this;
}
}
```

https://pastebin.com/6EGkHj6r

```
package main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import imageBuilders.Image;

public class JCanvas extends JPanel {

private static List<Image> li = new ArrayList<Image>();

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4456984789525563682L;


public JCanvas(){
    super();
}
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    for(Image i: li){
    try{    
    g.drawImage(i.getImage(), i.getX(), i.getY(), i.getImageObserver());
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
    }
    }
}

public static void addImage(Image i){
    li.add(i);
}

public static void removeImageinIndice(int i){
    li.remove(i);
}

public static void changeImageInIndice(int i, Image i2){
    li.add(i, i2);
}

public static void clearImages(){
    li.clear();
}

public static Image getImageinIndice(int i){
    return li.get(i);
}

public static boolean changeImageXandY(int x, int y, int ii){
    Image im = li.get(ii);

    im.setX(x);
    System.out.println(im.getX());
    im.setY(y);
    li.set(ii, im);
    return true;

}


public KeyListener getKeyListener(){
    return this.getKeyListener();
}


}
```

Comment: Search for DoubleBufferStrategy when creating a JPANEL (never override JFrame paint) and draw it in a secondary thread, I did forgot all the setup and startegy for a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Swing components (including JPanel) are already double buffered by default, so you won't benefit by trying to implement your own double buffering. Try overriding `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()` (which is the old AWT way to do things).

`paint()` actually includes a call to three different methods, one of which is `paintComponent()`, so when you're overriding `paint()`, you're painting borders and all children twice, which is probably why your UI is flickering.

For more details, read [The Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) and for even more details, read this Oracle [tech note](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Comment: I did Change that Thank you. It has not fixed it fully